# How to model a microphone metal mesh texture

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can a microphone mesh material texture be made in Blender?

Can it be made with textures, or is it made from some type of technique using modifiers? It has a weaved metal pattern with overlap, but I'm confused how I can even start to do this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've made a tuto on this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5eomi39Hlc), inspired by Yacine3Dz tuto [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOzkbxlgvVU).
Basically, create this pattern of 4 intertwined edges:

[image]

Give your object an *Array* on X, another one on Y, and a *Skin* modifier. Enable the *Smooth Shading* of the *Skin*, select the tip of each edge and press on the *Mark Root* button of the *Skin* modifier. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to increase the thickness of the vertices (also *N panel > Item > Vertex Data > Radius*):

[image]

Create a circle that you put on your grid object, subdivide it a bit, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Give your grid a *Surface Deform* modifier with your circle as *Target*, click on the *Bind* button, now you can move your circle away, and edit it in *Edit* mode to give the wanted shape:

[image]

You can bake the normals if you want a lighter object and convert to a texture.

Comment: Magic!

Thank you!